# Combining a TabBar and Navigation Controller IOS8

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios8, xcode6, tabbarcontroller

I'm new to iOS and I have troubles to display a navigation controller in my **taBbar** after Xcode 6 update.

With Xcode 5, it was working perfectly but now on the simulator I get an error message "**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'**" and the app crashes.
Here is my code:

```
**appDelegate.m**

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:      
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

*// tabBar items*

ItemUnViewController *itemUnViewController = [[ItemUnViewController alloc]
                                                          initWithNibName:nil
                                                          bundle:NULL];


ItemDeuxViewController *itemDeuxViewController = [[ItemDeuxViewController alloc]
                                                                initWithNibName:nil
                                                                bundle:NULL];

*//tabBar*

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:@[itemUnViewController,itemDeuxViewController]];


*//setting tabBar as rootView*

self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;


*// navigation Controllers*

UINavigationController *itemUnNavigationController =
[[UINavigationController alloc]
initWithRootViewController:itemUnViewController];

UINavigationController *itemDeuxNavigationController =
[[UINavigationController alloc]
initWithRootViewController:itemDeuxViewController];


*//Combining tabBar and Navigation Controllers*

[tabBarController setViewControllers:@        
[itemUnNavigationController,itemDeuxNavigationController]];

return YES;
}
```

I even tried this way http://blog.rifkilabs.net/exploring-navigation-controller-and-tab-bar-controller.html but i get the same error message.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
         tabBar_Controller = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
                [tabBar_Controller setDelegate:self];



            ViewController1 *obj_1 = [obj_story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC1"];
            UINavigationController *navi_vc1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:obj_1];
            navi_vc1.navigationBarHidden = YES;

        ViewController2 *obj_2 = [obj_story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2"];
            UINavigationController *navi_vc2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:obj_2];
            navi_vc2.navigationBarHidden = YES;


        [tabBar_Controller setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navi_vc1,navi_vc2,nil]];

     //Hide Tabbar View Controller.//
        [self hideTabBar]
    =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    -(void) hideTabBar
    {
        for(UIView *view in tabBar_Controller.view.subviews)
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }
            else
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
            }
        }
    }
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
-(void)create_BottomBarButton
{
    UIView *viewBottom = (UIView *)[self.window viewWithTag:Tag_BottomView];

    if (viewBottom == nil)
    {
        @try
        {
            viewBottom = [[UIView alloc]init];
            [viewBottom setFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.origin.x, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-(HeightOfBottomBar+KsubviewHeight), [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, HeightOfBottomBar)];
            [viewBottom setBackgroundColor:RGB(47.0, 45.0, 45.0, 1.0)];
            [viewBottom setTag:Tag_BottomView];
            NSArray *arrImage = [NSLocalizedString(@"arrBottomBarImgs", nil)componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
            float x = 0.0;
            for (int i =0; i < kTotalTab; i++) {
                [self create_TabBtn:viewBottom frame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 62,62) withTag:i+1 withImage:[arrImage objectAtIndex:i]];
                x += 64.5;
            }
            [self.window addSubview:viewBottom];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            NSLog(@"EXCEPTON %@",[exception description]);
        }
    }
}
-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-
-(void)select_Tab:(UIButton *)btn
{
    @try {
        [[tabBar_Controller.viewControllers objectAtIndex:btn.tag-1] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [tabBar_Controller setSelectedIndex:btn.tag-1];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
         NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }
}
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

```
-(void)pushTabBarIntoNavigationBar
{
    [navi setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [navi pushViewController:tabBar_Controller animated:YES];
}
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
navi = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tabBar_Controller];
[navi setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.window.rootViewController = navi;
```